# Way to visualize as tree a list of paths?

Tags: linux, tree, command-line-interface

I'd like to see a list of paths in a textfile as a tree in the command line.

I know about the tree utility in gnu/linux, but it seems to default to listing files in the filesystem. Is there a way to give it my list of paths from file so it builds its tree visualization from that instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the list of paths in the following format, like the output from the "find" command?

```
.
./aaa
./aaa/bbb
./aaa/ccc
./ddd
./ddd/eee
```

For example, using the "awk" command, I think you can get a format similar to the output of tree.

```sh
$ cat paths.txt | sort | awk '{n=split($0,a,/\//);for(i=1;i<n-1;i++)printf("|   ");if(n>1){printf("+-- ")}print a[n]}'
```